# Email alert if interface status changes

Tags: cisco, cisco-nx-os

I have two Nexus 5548s in our data center. They have only servers and storage connected to them. Some interfaces are configured for native fiber channel while the rest are still Ethernet. Since there will only be servers and storage connected, I'd like to get alerts if an interface status changes (goes from up to down or vice versa). I was able to successfully configure some alerts using  the "callhome" configuration using some of the default alert groups. For example, I configured the alert-group Environmental to email when it got a message-level 3. If I disconnect one of the power supplies (simulating power failure), it sends me an email. But I can't find how to configure an email for interface status change.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to have someone write a python script that sends an email. In the python script, I can specify the contents of the email. I then use EEM to specify the syslog pattern I want it to trigger on and use "action 1 cli local command "file_name.py"" to call the python script. This solution works on NX-OS 7.3(1)N1(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use eem - embeded event manager. Here is nx-os configuration guide: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/system_management/configuration/guide/sm_nx_os_cg/sm_12eem.html. First example shows how to send emails. With eem you can capture interface state changes and trigger events. Also nexus switches support pure python. You can write a python script which catches the int up down logs and sends notifications

Comment: I think my lack of experience is holding me up. I don't see how to get the email to send. Here is what I have so far:
`conf t  
event manager environment emailto "my_mail@abc.com"  
event manager applet link_status_down  
description "This event triggers when an interface link goes down"  
event syslog pattern "%PORT-5-IF_DOWN_LINK_FAILURE"  
action 1.0 event-default  
action 2.0  
copy run start`  

I left action 2 blank because that is where the email command needs to go, but I don't know how to generate that or use the emailto variable I set.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I can't get that to display how I want it to. The way it is displaying makes it look like the second action is copy run start, but that isn't right. Action 2 is actually blank, like I said. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: try this: http://www.ciscozine.com/send-email-from-your-router-using-eem/

Comment: Thank you again. In the ciscozine instructions, the command "action email server", the email switch doesn't exist in the current version of NX-OS.

Comment: I was able to confirm the "action email server" feature has be deprecated and no longer exists. The answer turns out to be a combination of a python script and EEM.